# Transaction rollback does not work in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, transactions, rollback

Basically, i have a Sampleapiclass class in which some files are retrieved into a list and the list is looped and for each file performAction is called. if a file fails validation, i want the transaction to roll back. The problem is, i tried annotating with rollback, but even if one file validation fails, transaction is not rolled bak.eg. file 1, succeeds, gets inserted, file 2 fails, but the file 1 is in the database. Any idea what might be wrong ?

As an additonal note, Sampleapiclass is initialied from  the main method , may be it has somethin to do that that ?
f.eks:  from main class

```
class MainClass
{
   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplContext ctx = new ClassPathxmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        MainClass app = ctx.getBean(MainClass.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
    void run()
    {
          Sampleapiclass api = new Sampleapiclass();
          DaoClass dao = new Sampleapiclass();
          api.apimethod(dao)
    }
}


class Sampleapiclass
{
    
    void apimethod(Dao daoclass)
    {
        serviceClass serviceClass = new ServiceCLass(daoclass);
        List<String> files = filesFromSomewhere
        for (String file: filesFromSomewhere)
        {
            try
             {
                serviceClass.performAction(file);
             }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}


class serviceClass
{
    private final Dao daoclass;
    public serviceClass(DaoClass daoclass) 
     {
        this.daoclass = daoclass;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    void performAction(String file) throws CustomException
    {
        dovalidation(file); // this method can throw CustomExeption if validation fails
        daoclass.insert(file)
    }
    dovalidation(String file) throws CustomExeption
    {
    if (file.endsWith("somethng") throw new CustomExeption();
    }
}       

class dao
{
    void insert(String file)
    {
    getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(parameters);
    }
}
```

Contents of app contetxt:

```
<bean class="Configbean class />
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${main.db.uri}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${main.db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${main.db.password}"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `dovalidation()` and `daoclass.insert()`?

Comment: updated the code @NeoChiri

Comment: `@Transaction` works when you are doing the db operation so for each file you are starting a new transaction therefore it won't rollback the previous one. I would suggest you run the loop inside `performAction()` instead.

Comment: i tried that too, no luck..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `@Transactional` works with AOP. AOP doesn't work on inclass method calls (due to Proxying). Try throwing an exception inside of your `@Transactional` for it to work or call a method outside of your class also marked with `@Transaction(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)`

also don't forget `@EnableTransactionManagement` over your `@Configuration` class

helpful resource https://javamondays.com/spring-transactions-explained/

Comment: well, i tried calling the  performAction from a test main class, still no luck, will have to debug tommorow.

Comment: from a main class  serviceClass service = new serviceClass(dao), then calling service.insert  and passing a list of files to insert where one fails, still no luck

Comment: another thing that might be causing the issue is using Transactional NOT inside of a spring bean - you should use it inside of Spring beans so that Spring takes care of instantiation and thus is able to create proxies and make @Transactional work

Comment: sorry, i have edited the question, everything is triggered from the main class

Comment: and that is why it won't work - no spring = no proxy = no transactional

Comment: but, even thouh it is called from main, i am loading the application contxext.   ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/application-context.xml");
        
        MainClass app = ctx.getBean(MainClass.class);  app.run()  ;    so shouldnt it work ?

Comment: that is not what your code shows - can you update your code in question to how you are actually doing it? also don't forget <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

Comment: done, edited the code, let me check the app context file

Comment: SampleApiClassannd ServiceClass need to be a Spring managed beans as well since @Transactional is used in it - please stop using new, the whole point of Spring is to move away from new.

Comment: ya, i think instead if new , i need to get the service class from the context, will try that tomorow, thanks for the input..